# Example of a non abelian group $G ,H,K$ and $N$ non trivial normal subgroups with some condition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to give example of a non abelian group $G$ such that $H,K$ and $N$ are its non trivial normal subgroups and $G= H \times K$ and $N$ is contained in the centre of $G$ and it intersects one of $H,K$ non trivially. Can somebody please tell?

Answer (score 1):

Take $G=C_4 \times Q$, where $Q$ is the quaternion group of order 8. Let $N=C_2 \times \{1\}$.

By the way:

**Theorem** If $N \unlhd G_1 \times G_2$, then either $N \subseteq Z(G_1 \times G_2)$ or $N$ intersects one of the factors $G_1$ or $G_2$ non-trivially.

Proof. Assume that $N \cap (G_1 \times$ {$1$}$)$ = {$(1,1)$} = $N \cap $({$1$} $\times$  $G_2)$. We will show that N is contained in the center of $G_1 \times G_2$. Fix an arbitrary $(n_1,n_2) \in N$. Let $g_1 \in G_1$. Since $N$ is normal, $(g_1,1)^{-1}·(n_1,n_2)·(g_1,1) = (g_1^{-1}n_1g_1, n_2) \in N.$ Obviously also $(n_1,n_2)^{-1} = (n_1^{-1},n_2^{-1}) \in N$. It follows that the product $(n_1^{-1},n_2^{-1})·(g_1^{-1}n_1g_1, n_2) = (n_1^{-1}g_1^{-1}n_1g_1, 1) \in N$. However, $N$ intersects $G_1 \times$ {$1$} trivially, whence $n_1^{-1}g_1^{-1}n_1g_1 = 1$, that is, $n_1$ commutes with every $g_1 \in G_1$. Similarly, $n_2$ commutes with every $g_2 \in G_2$. This means that $(n_1,n_2) \in Z(G_1) \times Z(G_2) = Z(G_1 \times G_2)$. $\square$

Comment: Sir can you please tell what this notation C_4 means?

Comment: $C_n$ is the (multiplicatively notated) cyclic group of order $n$. This is the same as the additively  notated $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

consider the group $G$ given by:

$G=\{i,-i,j,-j,k,-k,1,-1\}$

Define $i.j=k,j.k=i,k.i=j,j.i=-k,k.j=-i,i.k=-j$

Define $H=\{1,-1,i,-i\},K=\{1,-1,j,-j\};N=\{1,-1\}$

Comment: But $H \cap K \ne 1$, so we do not have $G = H \times K$.

Comment: To amplify Derek's comment, it's a well-known theorem that $Q_8$ is not even a semi-direct product, much less a direct product.