# How to finish the proof of: If $N\unlhd G=H\times K$, then $N$ is abelian or $N$ intersects $H \times \{e\}$ or $\{e\} \times K$ non trivially

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, direct-product

Question:  Let $N$ is normal to $G=H\times K$, Prove that $N$ is abelian or $N$ intersects one of $H \times \{e\}$ or $\{e\} \times K$ non trivially.

Solution:  Since $G=H\times K$, then $G$ can be written as an internal direct product of $H$ and $K$, then $H\cap K=\{e\}$ Suppose $h\in H$ and $k\in K$ and $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}\in H\cap K$, then $hk=kh$, where $e$ denotes the identity of both $H$ and $K$.  Hence $Nhkh^{-1}k^{-1}=N$, $Nhk=Nkh$. Also, $Nhk=NhNk=Nkh=NkNh$. So $NhNk=NkNh$.  Hence $N$ is a normal abelian group.   If we interpret $G=H\times K$ as the external direct product, then $H\times K=(H\times \{e\})\cdot(\{e\}\times K)$.  Also, since $N\leq (H\times K)$, then $H\cong (H\times \{e\})$, $K\cong (\{e\}\times K)$, $N\cong (N\times \{e\})$ and $N\cong (\{e\}\times N)$, so

$$\begin{align} N\times N&\cong (N\times \{e\})\cdot (\{e\}\times N)\\
&\cong N\cdot N \in N.
\end{align}$$

Can I conclude at this point that both $N\cap H$ and $N\cap K$ are non empty?

Thank you in advance

Comment: @Shaun wait, I don't understand what I am doing wrong.  Did I not shown tha $N$ is abelian?  I just used what I can conclude from $G=H\times K$ as either the external or internal direct product and their respective properties.

Comment: @Shaun I posted a screenshot of where the  question is from and also corrected the phrasing to match what it says in the screenshot.

Comment: No  you didn't show that $N$ is abelian. You just wrote "Hence $N$ is an abelian group" without any explanation. Why do you think that $Nhk=Nkh$ for $h \in H$ and $k \in K$ implies that $N$ is abelian?

Comment: Do not use images to convey information not otherwise present in your post. [You've been here long enough to know that by now](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/742).

Comment: You showed that the coset, relative to $N$, of an element of $H$ commutes with the coset of an element of $K$. That is, that $HN/N$ commutes elementwise with $KN/N$ in $G/N$. But since $H$ and $K$ already commuted elementwise in $G$, all you did was note that if two elements commuted in $G$ then they commute in a quotient of $G$. You spun your wheels, and proved nothing.

Comment: What is the point of the image, with three utterly irrelevant items, plus the messing up for the formatting?

Comment: $N\times N$ is a subgroup of $G\times G$. It is not a subgroup of $G$. And $N$ is not an element of itself. The displayed equation is complete, total nonsense. Do you understand what the symbols mean, or are you just throwing up stuff at the wall to see if something sticks?

Comment: @DerekHolt I just edit my post giving further reasoning as to why N is abelian.

Comment: You gave no "reasoning" showing $N$ is abelian. Nowhere do you even begin to see whether any two **elements** of $N$ commute with one another. Not only are you not showing or giving evidence that $N$ is abelian, you aren't even in the correct continent to show $N$ is abelian.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am using Hungerford's text.  From your solution, I think it suppose I have learned central series and the term central is not in Hungerford's undergrad text.  The question came from another book in Direct product chapter after normal and central series made an appearance.

Comment: @SethMai my solution has nothing to do with central series. The only thing I am using is the center of a group. An element is central if it lies in the center, if it commutes with everything in the group. You are completely lost, and clearly need to go back and relearn the basics. You appear to have no idea what it means for a group to be abelian, for example. Given your state of complete confusion and utter incomprehension, you should not be looking at exercises from other books, since you can't even understand the book you are using.

Comment: This post is relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166690/example-of-a-non-abelian-group-g-h-k-and-n-non-trivial-normal-subgroups-wit?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $N$ is normal, and nonabelian. Since it is nonabelian, there exists an element $(h,k)\in N$ such that either $h$ is not central in $H$, or $k$ is not central in $K$ (if both $h\in Z(H)$ and $k\in Z(K)$, then $(h,k)\in Z(G)$, hence it commutes with everything in $G$, and thus in $N$).

If $h\notin Z(H)$, then there exists $h'\in H$ such that $h'h(h')^{-1}\neq h$. Since $N$ is normal in $G$, then
$(h',e)(h,k)(h',e)^{-1} = (h'h(h')^{-1},k)\in N$. Therefore,
$$(h',e)(h,k)(h',e)(h,k)^{-1} = (h'h(h')^{-1}h^{-1},e)\in N.$$
Since $h'$ and $h$ do not commute, this is a nontrivial element of $H\times \{e\}$. Thus, $N$ intersects $H\times\{e\}$ nontrivially.

If $k\notin Z(K)$, then a symmetric argument shows that $N$ intersects $\{e\}\times K$ nontrivially.

Thus, if $N$ is normal, then either $N$ is abelian, or else $N$ intersects either $H\times\{e\}$ or $\{e\}\times K$ nontrivially.

Note that in fact we established more: the argument holds if $N$ contains an element that is not in $Z(H)\times Z(K) = Z(G)$; so if $N\triangleleft H\times K$, either $N$ is **central**, or else it intersects $H\times\{e\}$ or $\{e\}\times K$ nontrivially.

---

If you don't know what the center is, you don't need it. If $N$ is nonabelian find two elements $(h_1,k_1)$ and $(h_2,k_2)$ of $N$ that do not commute. We must have either the $h_i$ nontrivial do not commute, or the $k_i$ nontrivial do not commute. In the first case, conjugate $(h_1,k_1)$ by $(h_2,e)$ and proceed as before. In the latter, conjugate by $(e,k_2)$.

Comment: I edit my post just now about showing $N$ is abelian.  Also from your comment, I think the way I am trying to show non trivial intersection is incorrect.

Comment: @SethMai Your edits are not even wrong. They are nonsense. They are a bunch of words that make no sense whatsoever.

Comment: if $G$ is written as an internal direct product of its subgroups, then there are properties about the internal direct product I can make use of and relate it back to N as a normal subgroup.  Also is it possible to give a direct proof?

Comment: @SethMai Your first sentence is true but irrelevant, as you are doing nothing of the sort. And I **gave** a direct proof.  A proof of "not(A) implies B" **is** a direct proof of "A or B", and I do not make any arguments by contradiction. Your comment demonstrates a complete lack of understanding.

Comment: I asked a friend about this question, and from our conversation, I thought I have to show that N is abelian or N has non trivial.....  Also when I have a group say $N$ and when it intersects with a direct product of groups.  I don't know what that means notationally.  But your solution clarified for me.  Thank you so very much.